# Retrieve ASP.NET Membership Security Question

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I am implementing a reset password aspx page and in that page, I am doing the following with a Wizard.

1. I am asking the user for his/her username, checking to make sure username does exist before moving on.
2. In the second view, I want to ask the user to answer his/her security question. I want to display the question and validate what their answer is, and if valid, continue to third step. (At moment, I'm not sure how to retrieve the security question to display in the second.)
3. In third view, ask user to enter in new password.

I understand how to go about changing the password even without the old password, but just can't seem to figure out how to get the security question.

Anyone have any ideas??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Membership.GetUser().PasswordQuestion` contains the Security Question.

`Membership.GetUser().ResetPassword(securityQuestionAnswer)` will generate a new random password for the user.  You can then email this to the user.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d90zte4w.aspx

If a password answer is required and an incorrect password answer is supplied, a `MembershipPasswordException` is thrown by the membership provider.  If you wanted to allow the user to enter a password,  you could check to ensure that this exception is not thrown, then change the password.

Comment: "You can then email this to the user." -- **Please do not send passwords in e-mails!**

Comment: @FilipEkberg What do can/should the ASP.NET code do with the password except for sending it via email? Sending it via email, at least, requires the user to have access to the registered email account.

Comment: @ChrisW, What? A better way is to generate a unique link sent to the users registered e-mail then ask the user to enter a new password when at that link. Having passwords sent to e-mail is bad practice..

Comment: @FilipEkberg Thanks for your reply. That "unique link" is an implicit authentication of the user, sent by email. Why would that be a better practice than sending a one-time-use password (to be changed again when the user uses it)? Or is the difference only that it can only be used once?

Comment: @ChrisW, The link should still only be usable once and expire after a certain time. To retrieve the link you should be required to answer the security question. Sending passwords in clear text in emails is always bad practice, even if it is just a one time thing, it's bad practice.